# SELECT my_value FROM all_tables WHERE myopt='options';

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

How can I make query like that in SQL Server?

```
SELECT my_value 
FROM all_tables 
WHERE myopt = 'options';
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'options'? Is it a list of possible values, for which SQL would use:  select my_value FROM my_table where myop in ('A','B','C')? or are you stressing "ALL" when you "all_tables?

Comment: I believe the user is looking for one attribute being a certain value, across many tables.

Comment: are you asking for the syntax to query a mysql database?

Comment: I would like something this:
SELECT surname FROM all_tables_in_database WHERE name='John';

Comment: You cannot do this - there's no way to select *from all tables* at once...

Comment: Look up UNION. You will need this to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: as@marc_s suggested, no way to do. Just try by adding one by one table in union as    select surname from table1 unionn select surname from table2 union...

Comment: I suppose they mean UNION ALL...

Comment: problem with UNION is that I must know table names.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use sp_MSforeachtable SP (an unsupported command from Microsoft) which will allow you to issue a command for every table in a database.

exec sp_MSforeachtable 'select top 1 * from ? '

The question mark will be replaced with every tablename in the current database.

You can also loop through all the tables by writing your own code. Here is an example that will list the first row of every table in a database. Notice I did not use cursors which causes great agita to some users:

declare @curtable nvarchar(500)

declare @sqlstr nvarchar(500)

set nocount on

select '['+ t1.TABLE_SCHEMA +'].[' + t1.TABLE_NAME +']' as tablename

into  ##t5
 from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t1

where TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'

order by t1.TABLE_SCHEMA +'.' + t1.TABLE_NAME

select Top 1 @curtable = tablename from ##t5

while @curtable is not null

begin

```
select @curtable

set @sqlstr = N'select top 1 *   from '+@curtable+' with (nolock)'

print @sqlstr

exec sp_executesql @sqlstr

delete from ##t5 where tablename = @curtable

set @curtable= null 

select @curtable = tablename from ##t5
```

end

Comment: You should rewrite your code so it matches OP's question - so your first snippet should be something like `EXEC sys.sp_MSforeachtable 'SELECT my_value FROM ? WHERE myopt = ''options'''` you should also adapt the second approach accordingly.

Comment: Just nitpicking: `MSforeachtable` is not unsupported (otherwise you could not call it I suppose), but undocumented. And the usage of cursors is not so much frowned upon just because of the cursors, but because they break the set-based operation style of sql (i.e. **no** loops) in your script